# Mule: Access file resource from Python script component in CloudHub

Tags: mule, cloudhub, anypoint-studio

In a mule project, I have a Python script component that needs to access a cert.pem file.

In AnyPointStudio I've placed it in the ./src/main/resources/ folder.
When I create a Mule Deployable Archive, it ends up in the ./target/classes/ folder.

What path should I specify to access this file.

I've tried

```
path = 'cert.pem'

## And ## 

cwd = os.getcwd()
path = os.path.join(cwd, 'classes','cert.pem')
path = os.path.join(cwd, 'target','classes','cert.pem')
path = os.path.join(cwd, 'src','main', 'resources','cert.pem')
```

None of which work.
Any advice?

Side Question:
In CloudHub simple `print()` statements in the .py script don't log, I tried `log("message")` but that raised an exception. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know python, but the file should just be available on the classpath. So everything in src/main/resources will be available on the classpath. So 'src/main/resources/cert.pem' should just be referenced as 'cert.pem'

Answer (score 0):

So, at least with Python, the classes path isn't the same as working directory path. But I did eventually figure out how to get at the classes path using the MULE_HOME env variable.

```
base = os.path.join(os.getenv('MULE_HOME'), 'apps', 'your-app-name', 'classes')
```

Then you can get the certfile like this:

```
certfile = os.path.join(base, 'cert.pem')
```